# Fixing width/height of an element to whatever it is

Tags: css, responsive-design, height, width

I have a `div` element that is supposed to be a horizontal main menu. I used a `ul` and its `li`s as menu items. `li`s are `inline-block` so they make a horizontal menu. I set the `div`'s width to 100 percent but I didn't set any height for the `div`, so its height is defined by its paddings, borders and contents. Now I want to fix its height to whatever it is (without directly defining), so I can use `overflow` to hide overflowed menu items on smaller screen sizes. I think it would be good for responsive designs. Can it be done with pure CSS?

Currently, as I make the browser's width smaller, menu items pile up, make more than 1 row of menu items and force the `div`'s height to fit. I want to see only the first row of menu items.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure the contents of the div stay on one line using the css

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

If you want multiple lines, you can do something like

```
max-height: 3em; (or whatever value is appropriate)
```

Beware of how the overflowing content looks as it spills out of the element, it may abruptly clip out of view and look a bit nasty. If it is just text you can use

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But if you are dealing with actual elements, it's more complex! It's possible to create nice fades using only css and pseudo elements though, that's what I would do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your first suggestion was kind of what I want. Please see my edited question. You can see that I want menu items to totally disappear when even a part of them tries to go outside the borders of menu.